# Open System Preferences/Privacy/Full Disk Access with url

Tags: security, privacy, url

I can open System Preferences/Privacy/Automation on Mojave with the URL

```
x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Automation
```

What is the equivalent to open Full Disk Access? Tried `x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_FullDiskAccess` and similar, but this didn't work.

Answer (score 8):

```
x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_AllFiles
```

You can list all the available anchors for the pane by opening the pane and running the AppleScript

```
tell application "System Preferences" to get name of anchors of current pane
```

This returns the following list:

- Advanced
- FDE
- Firewall
- General
- Privacy
- Privacy_Accessibility
- **Privacy_AllFiles**
- Privacy_Assistive
- Privacy_Calendars
- Privacy_Camera
- Privacy_Contacts
- Privacy_Diagnostics
- Privacy_LinkedIn
- Privacy_LocationServices
- Privacy_Microphone
- Privacy_Reminders
- Privacy_SystemServices

Comment: I'll add this as a separate question if it's possible - but based on that is it possible to add an app to, for instance the Microphone list, if it hasn't been added automatically? So far, manual addition to that has eluded me & some apps just don't correctly call gatekeeper to add automatically.