# macOS 13 Beta: Usual link no longer opens Pref Pane for Full Disk Access

Tags: applescript, security, system-settings, preferences

In versions of macOS up to and including 12.x, the following link directly opened the Preferences Pane for Full Disk Access:

```
x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_AllFiles
```

As of the current macOS 13 beta, this link no longer behaves that way.  It instead opens the pane for Files and Folders.

Is there still a link to open the pane for Full Disk Access?

Note:  the answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361045/open-system-preferences-privacy-full-disk-access-with-url/361048#361048?newreg=6e9c3ecfed7e4ba79289c1bbc1f579e5) is a very good one, but it doesn't work in macOS 13.  In macOS 12, the AppleScript snippet works as the author describes.  In 13, it prints this error:  `temp.osa:45:49: execution error: System Settings got an error: AppleEvent handler failed. (-10000)`

**Edit**: I apologize for not providing the exact version information in this question. In my answer below, I have provided exact version information for the *next* beta I received, where the problem is fixed. Unfortunately, I now cannot go back in time to capture the exact version info for the beta version that this question was written about.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in macOS 13 Beta 2.  The URL in the original question now opens the Full Disk Access panel as it did before.

**Edit**:  To clarify what I mean by "Beta 2," this is the version I am using currently (where the problem is resolved):

```
% sw_vers
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 13.0
BuildVersion:   22A5286j
```

Comment: Awesome result. To avoid downvotes on beta questions, we recommend you post detailed build versions from `sw_vers` - ideally the version from beta 1 that you received and then again on the version you found the fix.. (since developer beta can differ from seed beta and public beta)

Comment: Thanks for the tip @bmike!  I added the version information to my answer (i.e., version where it's fixed).  Unfortunately, I have no way to go back to the previous beta build to get the original version info (version where I saw the problem), so I cannot update the original question with that info.

Comment: Beta 1 build: 22A5266r @bmike developer and public betas have been identical for over a year - same build number but with the "public" release a day later. Now that anyone can install the "developer" download the difference is moot.